# A way to make my app consume less ram

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I have a `Service` that execute a `AlarmManager` to repeat every 10 seconds to show a `Toast`.
i noticed that my `Service` take 12 mb from my RAM.thats alot,is there a way to make it take less ram?maybe a diffrenet way to launcher to `Toast` every 10 seconds?

Comment: Why do you want to display a Toast message every 10 seconds?

Comment: "i noticed that my Service take 12 mb from my RAM" -- how precisely did you determine this?

Comment: @Michelle This is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

Check for multiple allocation of variables for same values. Eliminate them and reuse values as many times as possible.

Comment: Thats great,its actually helped a little(9 mb),but for that simple app its still takes to much

Answer (score 2):

It's really good you are thinking about these kind of issues, but also remember to measure with metrics too.

So my advice would be to prove to yourself that you can or can't reduce the foot print by creating a dummy app that does practically nothing and then observe its memory footprint. Then decide how much time you want to invest in optimizing your app.

Comment: as i answered to KaranJ i eliminated some unused variables,created an non dummy app(did you advice and it was a good one).any more suggestions?

Comment: what resources do you have? Do you have any extra/not needed. I bet images,etc in the apk will affect RAM, but haven't looked into it.

Comment: hmm actually i have nothing.
as i said just a service launching a broadcast that showing a toast using alarmManager every 10 seconds

Comment: What is the foot print of a dummy app vs your app?

Comment: ive deleted the dummy app,how can i send you the footprint?

Comment: do you remember roughly how much memory your app vs the dummy app consumed?

Comment: yea : dummy - about 12 mb,app - about 9 mb